# React Native StatusBar translucent not setting to true when app is resumed on android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-statusbar

Mostly it works perfectly, but sometimes when you minimise the app and you try to resume the app, it starts over again and **the StatusBar won't be translucent** (i.e the StatusBar will be shown). Thanks

i was thinking maybe the issue if from android onResume function.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, it was because it was opening a new instance each time i opened the app, could you try to add this line to your activity in src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <activity
       android:name=".MainActivity"
       ...
       android:launchMode="singleInstance"> <-- This
```